# What problem type the Power Set belong to?

Tags: knapsack-problem, np, np-complete, np-hard, halting-problem

I don't seem to find any much resource about "Power Set" problem.

Is Power Set a NP-Complete or NP-Hard problem? And why? Can someone advise me?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a computer programming question. It is a question about the theory of computation.

Comment: @RaymondChen i am sorry about because i mostly find any algorithm problem in stack overflow. I didnot know they changed the policy

Comment: Do u know where can i post something like this?

Comment: [cs.se] is for computer science questions.